# Codeception - Can't connect to Webdriver (Acceptance Test)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I can access url and create sessions:

> http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html

but when i execute `./codecept run` i get an error, but i have Selenium Server running:

```
[ConnectionException] Can't connect to Webdriver at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub. Please make sure that Selenium Server or PhantomJS is running.
```

[image: error connecting to webdriver]

To execute Selenium Server, i used this command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver -jar "selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar"
```

[image: selenium server running]

I tried too with IE and Chrome (i have the same problem too):

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver -jar "selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar"
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./IEDriverServer -jar "selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar"
```

**acceptance.suite.yml**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost'
            browser: firefox
            window_size: 820x1000
```

- **Codeception Version:** 2.4.1
- **WebDriver Chrome Version:** 2.38 (win32)
- **WebDriver Firefox Version:** 0.20.1 (x64)
- **Chrome Version:** 66.0.3359.139 (64-bit)
- **Firefox Version:** Firefox Quantum 60.0 (64-bit)
- **Windows Version:** Windows 8.1 64bit
- **Selenium Version:** 3.12.0

Comment: Running into the same issue here.  The proxy solution didn't work for me.   When I run a test, I get an error that JSON decoding of remote response failed: "The requested resource \<code class="url">/wd/hub/session\</code> was not found on this server."

Answer (score 5):

To start **Selenium Server** you need not require to pass/specify the *WebDriver* variant and you can start the **Selenium Server** as follows :

- Command :

  ```
  >java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
  ```
- Console Logs :

  ```
  C:\Utility\selenium-server-standalone>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
  15:28:28.249 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3'
  15:28:28.251 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
  2018-05-11 15:28:28.361:INFO::main: Logging initialized @467ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
  15:28:28.860 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
  ```
- Snapshot of the *Resource Hub* :

  [image: static_resource_hub]

---

### Update

As per the documentation at [**`codeception.com`**](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver) the `acceptance.suite.yml` should have been as follows :

```
modules:
    enabled:
    - WebDriver:
       url: 'http://localhost/'
       browser: firefox
       window_size: 820x1000
```

Comment: With your example i can access the link too, but i get the same error when i execute codeception.

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: Same thing. :(
url required - Starting URL for your app.
browser required - Browser to launch.
host - Selenium server host (127.0.0.1 by default).
port - Selenium server port (4444 by default).
From: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed. **I was using proxy.**

For future users with same problem like me, can follow the steps.

- First, check if you have proxy defined with this command:

`echo %http_proxy%`

- If return some result, you need set a empty proxy with this command:

`set http_proxy=`

You need define a proxy always you are opening a new command line.